# Rstudio extract file extensions from a data table containing all files in a directory

Tags: r, string, data.table, substring

I have the following table "test":

```
vars <- c("abc.pdf", "def.xlsx")
test <- as.data.table(vars)
```

How can create a column extracting the extension of the file, i.e. "pdf, "xlsx" or whatever is on the right of the dot?
Thanks and best regards!

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways:

```
test
test[, ext := tstrsplit(vars, "\\.")[[2]]]
test[, ext2 := sub("^.+\\.", "", vars)]
#       vars  ext ext2
# 1:  abc.pdf  pdf  pdf
# 2: def.xlsx xlsx xlsx
```

Comment: How can I get: "abc" and "def"? In my case I have the entire directory: dir/abc.pdf I would like to get the part between the last dot and the last slash.

Comment: That would probably be a new question.

Comment: This is indeed why I create a separe  topic! But it has been aggregated to this one.